# Retrieve data in oracle

Tags: oracle

Table description:

BRANCH(Branchid,Branchname,HOD)
STUDENT(USN,Name,Address,Branchid,sem)
BOOK(Bookid,Bookname,Authorid,Publisher,Branchid) 
AUTHOR(Authorid,Authorname,Country,age)
BORROW(USN,Bookid,Borrowed_Date)

Q1) Display the student details who borrowed books of more than one Author.
Q2)List the details of students who borrowed the books which are all published by the same 
Publisher.

Comment: What are you using to pull the information? Are you just looking for a SQL query?

Comment: Yes. Just a sql query

Comment: And which bit of your homework assignment is giving you a problem?

Comment: @APC ha ha ha, Yah I am thinking that is it as well.

Answer (score 0):

TRY THIS:

```
SELECT  
 S.NAME             AS "STUDENT NAME"
,S.ADDRESS          AS "STUDENT ADDRESS"
,BW.BORROWED_DATE   AS "DATE BORROWED"
,BR.BRANCHNAME      AS "BRANCE NAME"
,BK.BOOKNAME        AS "NAME OF BOOK"
,BK.PUBLISHER       AS "BOOK PUBLISHER"
,A.AUTHORNAME       AS "NAME OF AUTHOR"
,A.COUNTRY          AS "COUNTRY OF AUTHOR"
,A.AGE              AS "AGE OF AUTHOR"
---
FROM 
STUDENT S
---
JOIN BORROW BW
    ON S.USN = BW.USN
--- 
JOIN BOOK BK
    ON BW.BOOKID = BK.BOOKID
--    
JOIN BRANCH BR
    ON BR.BRANCHID = BK.BRANCHID
---
JOIN AUTHOR A
    ON BK.AUTHORID = A.AUTHORID
--
--
JOIN (SELECT P1
        FROM (
            SELECT 
             SS_S.USN       "P1"
            ,SS_A.Authorid  "P2"
            FROM 
            STUDENT SS_S
            JOIN BORROW SS_BW
                ON SS_S.USN = SS_BW.USN
            JOIN BOOK SS_BK
                ON SS_BW.BOOKID = SS_BK.BOOKID
            JOIN AUTHOR SS_A
                ON SS_BK.AUTHORID = SS_A.AUTHORID
            GROUP BY 
             SS_S.USN
            ,SS_A.Authorid
            HAVING COUNT(SS_A.Authorid) > 1
        )
    ) SUB_Q
ON S.USN = SUB_Q.P1
ORDER BY 1, 3
```

QUESTION NUMBER 2 IS SIMPLE

```
SELECT  
 S.NAME             AS "STUDENT NAME"
,S.ADDRESS          AS "STUDENT ADDRESS"
,BW.BORROWED_DATE   AS "DATE BORROWED"
,BR.BRANCHNAME      AS "BRANCE NAME"
,BK.BOOKNAME        AS "NAME OF BOOK"
,BK.PUBLISHER       AS "BOOK PUBLISHER"
,A.AUTHORNAME       AS "NAME OF AUTHOR"
,A.COUNTRY          AS "COUNTRY OF AUTHOR"
,A.AGE              AS "AGE OF AUTHOR"
---
FROM 
STUDENT S
---
JOIN BORROW BW
    ON S.USN = BW.USN
--- 
JOIN BOOK BK
    ON BW.BOOKID = BK.BOOKID
--    
JOIN BRANCH BR
    ON BR.BRANCHID = BK.BRANCHID
---
JOIN AUTHOR A
    ON BK.AUTHORID = A.AUTHORID
--
WHERE 
BK.PUBLISHER = ''
```

Comment: Okay I am willing to help, but not with ½ sentences and no description for anything. "doesn't work" just doesn't work for me. -Did you get an error, did it return no results? You don't include what format your data is in or include example data sets. There can be conversion issues or a host of other problems. -Need input.

Comment: I have created a database and filled it with dummy information. The edited code above **DOES** work. I have created the example [here](https://livesql.oracle.com/apex/livesql/s/esc36mxws4dbijsm2qlbvv9hz)